# how to parse a txt file to csv and modify formatting

Tags: python, csv

Is there a way I can use python to take my animals.txt file results and convert it to csv and format it differently?

Currently the animals.txt file looks like this:

```
ID:- 512
NAME:- GOOSE
PROJECT NAME:- Random
REPORT ID:- 30321
REPORT NAME:- ANIMAL
KEYWORDS:- ['"help,goose,Grease,GB"']


ID:- 566
NAME:- MOOSE
PROJECT NAME:- Random
REPORT ID:- 30213
REPORT NAME:- ANIMAL
KEYWORDS:- ['"Moose, boar, hansel"']
```

I would like the CSV file to present it as:

```
ID, NAME, PROJECT NAME, REPORT ID, REPORT NAME, KEYWORDS
```

Followed by the results underneath each header

Here is a script I have wrote:

```
import re
import csv
with open("animals.txt") as f: text = f.read()

data = {}
keys = ['ID', 'NAME', 'PROJECT NAME', 'REPORT ID', 'REPORT NAME', 'KEYWORDS']
for k in keys:
    data[k] = re.findall(r'%s:- (.*)' % k, text)


csv_file = 'out.csv'

with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=keys) 
    writer.writeheader()
    for x in data:
        writer.writerow(x)
```

Comment: You basically want to change a json format into a tabular format?

Comment: "You basically want to change a json format into a tabular format?" - No I have a script which pulls from a DB and aquires these fields. The "Keywords" Column is displayed as JSON, however I want the JSON format to remain in the csv field as is

Comment: Do you have more than those "columns"? If not, you could extract the data via regex.

Comment: Your `lines` were not organized by keys, they were just in original order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do is parsing using regex and store them in a dict, just before you write the final csv:

```
import re

# `text` is your input text

data = {}
keys = ['ID', 'NAME', 'PROJECT NAME', 'REPORT ID', 'REPORT NAME', 'KEYWORDS']
for k in keys:
    data[k] = re.findall(r'%s:- (.*)' % k, text)
```

And to CSV:

```
import csv

csv_file = 'out.csv'

with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
    writer.writerow(data.keys())
    for i in range(len(data[keys[0]])):
        writer.writerow([data[k][i] for k in keys])
```

Output in csv:

```
ID,NAME,PROJECT NAME,REPORT ID,REPORT NAME,KEYWORDS
512,GOOSE,Random,30321,ANIMAL,['\"help\,goose\,Grease\,GB\"']
566,MOOSE,Random,30213,ANIMAL,['\"Moose\, boar\, hansel\"']
```

---

Note that I used `re.M` multiline mode since there's a trick in your text, preventing matching `ID` twice! Also the default write rows needed to be twisted.

Also uses `\` to escape the quote.

Comment: Thanks, my text is in a .txt file though, do I pass this in?

Comment: @user3296793 I believe you must have heard `with open(filename) as f: text = f.read()`

Comment: So the script runs, however it is displaying the CSV with items in incorrect fields and it only has 4 rows when it should have many many rows

Comment: Yep that works for the most part thank you, mine seems to print the column names in a random order - Starting with Project Name

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
fname = 'animals.txt'

with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]

output = 'ID, NAME, PROJECT NAME, REPORT ID, REPORT NAME, KEYWORDS\n'

line_output = ''
for i in range(0, len(content)):
    if content[i]:
        line_output += content[i].split(':-')[-1].strip() + ','
    elif not content[i] and not content[i - 1]:
        output += line_output.rstrip(',') + '\n'
        line_output = ''

output += line_output.rstrip(',') + '\n'

print(output)
```

Comment: This converts to CSV?

Comment: You can write `output` to a file and you will get a csv file or just append all the stuff to file instead of appending it to `output`. Although I would suggest using answer provided by knh190 which I think is better but not so much begginer friendly.

Answer (score -2):

That's the code in Autoit (www.autoitscript.com)

```
Global $values_A = StringRegExp(FileRead("json.txt"), '[ID|NAME|KEYWORDS]:-\s(.*)?', 3)
For $i = 0 To UBound($values_A) - 1 Step +6
    FileWrite('out.csv', $values_A[$i] & ',' & $values_A[$i + 1] & ',' & $values_A[$i + 2] & ',' & $values_A[$i + 3] & ',' & $values_A[$i + 4] & ',' & $values_A[$i + 5] & @CRLF)
Next
```

Comment: What is that? Perl? But this is a Python question.